# gvNix, problemas con la ingeniería inversa en SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, gvnix

Buenas,

no logro que el comando

```
database introspect --schema dbo
```

funcione correctamente. Cada vez que lo ejecuto recibo el mensaje

> Connection reset

pasados unos segundos.
He configurado correctamente la persistencia e instalado el driver de jtds.
Usando las mismas credenciales puedo conectarme sin problemas a la base de datos con RazorSQL.

Gracias

Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

[RESUELTO]
El problema estaba en el tipo de autenticación del usuario. Lo hemos cambiado a modo mixto y en la cadena de conexión no se le pone el dominio, de tal forma que se conecta siempre como usuario de SqlServer